# Can you continue an ILS approach when weather falls below minimum?

Tags: weather, approach, ils

If, after passing the final approach fix, weather deteriorates so that the reported values are now below required minima, is it allowed to continue the approach?

Answer (score 1):

You didn't list a jurisdiction so Ill answer for the FAA: Yes you can continue;

[Under part 91 you can both start and fly an approach if the conditions are below minimum.](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/53721/what-does-it-mean-when-your-destination-airport-is-currently-below-ifr-minimums)

If you are flying under part 121 then you can't start the approach but ***[§ 121.651 Takeoff and landing weather minimums: IFR: All certificate holders.](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/14/121.651)*** is going to be the regulation to reference and allows you to continue if you are passed the FAF.

> (c) A pilot who has begun the final approach segment of an instrument
>   approach procedure in accordance with paragraph (b) of this section,
>   and after that **receives a later weather report indicating
>   below-minimum conditions, may continue the approach to DA/DH or MDA**.
>   Upon reaching DA/DH or at MDA, and at any time before the missed
>   approach point, the pilot may continue the approach below DA/DH or MDA
>   if either the requirements of § 91.176 of this chapter, or the
>   following requirements are met: