# What are the operational differences between the ILS CATs?

Tags: ils

I know ILS CAT is classified by DH, and RVR, but I want to know what's difference between ILS CAT operationally.

For example, CAT 3 approach should be autolanding. (I am not sure)

And, if RVR is 600m which is CAT 1 RVR, Do pilot can make CAT 2 approach or should pilot make CAT 1 approach?

Comment: If you are asking the difference between two things you need to mention what both of them are in the title. If instead you are asking different types of CAT then that would sound like a 'search it' problem.

Comment: Related: [How do you choose CAT II vs. CATIII ILS?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/14624/how-do-you-choose-cat-ii-vs-catiii-ils)

Comment: Also related: [What is the purpose of having different ILS categories?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/35264/what-is-the-purpose-of-having-different-ils-categories)

Comment: Since you're asking about the operational aspect with an example of when to use auto land, does this answer your question? [When do pilots perform a CAT II/III autoland?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/55730/when-do-pilots-perform-a-cat-ii-iii-autoland) If not, you can edit the question to include more details to differentiate both topics.